What is the formatting for PNPDeviceID?
When I get PNPDeviceID for a certain COMXX, I am getting back this: USB\VID_067B&PID_2303\5&27699D6T&0&10
I understand the 4 digits after the VID and PID, but what is the last part "5&27699D6T&0&10"
Similarly for this device: FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6015+FT5Y36XFA\0000
What is the part "FT5Y36XFA\0000"
I looked through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-identification-strings, but I wasn't able to get a straight answer from that documentation, and couldn't find a PNPDeviceID format that matches mine
Looked through: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-identification-strings
